# when does kernel send TCP buffered data to the other end?

Tags: tcp

I have a question about the socket send buffer of TCP. As the syscall of "write" only means that the send buffer is available, and the "write" returns only when all data are copied into the buffer and not assumes the data are sent out.

So I have a question that if the end part of an application request doesn't fill the send buffer, when will kernel send out the data, as I haven't seen any system calls to let the user process control when to send all buffer data.

Comment: The behavior depends a lot on if the socket is blocking or not, and if [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) (`TCP_NODELAY` socket option) is enabled or not. Generally, data will be sent as soon as possible (Nagle's algorithm is disabled), no matter if the buffers are full or not.

Comment: I think it also has something to do with the PUSH flag according to Richard Steven's explanation of push flag.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I cannot see the relationship with the socket blocking option. But I think the Nagle part is logical, and may also combine with the PSH flag.